# Incrementing result as integer array digits in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have a function which calls another function and checks for condition to see if it's true, then it increments an integer. It's all fine and working but there will be a problem for very large results. It couldn't fit even in long long.

Example:

```
unsigned long long div(int num_first[], int num_second[])
{
    unsigned long long div_result = 0;

    while (compare(num_first, num_second) != -1)
    {
        divsub(num_first, num_second);
        div_result++;
    }

    return div_result; // return div_result to main
}
```

That function works fine, but if `div_result` gets too large it crashes or causes undefined behavior. I want to store its result as array like so:

```
div_result = 25464878454
```

I want it to be:

```
div_result[max] = {2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7, 8, 4, 5, 4}
```

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT:
I decided to use `unsigned long long` as folks suggest. That suits my case.**

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why an array and not a simple comparison to a `max` to take appropriate actions (i.e. like increment another counter to keep track of the number of times you reach `max`?)

Comment: It needs to be an array... another counter is not a good idea.

Comment: what about `unsigned long long` then you would have duplicated the range

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes they don't really matter here. problem is div_result

Comment: Do this while break?

Comment: you could also use a bigint library

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes of course. at some point.

Comment: @j.holetzeck don't want to use no library.

Comment: Make `div_result` a big number array too, like your operands.

Comment: Anyway, `return div_result;` the function is type `int` so that won't work.

Comment: @WeatherVane how can i fix return?? make it int64?

Comment: Your "Array" solution is really another counter if you think about it - in fact, every element of that array will roll over when the previous element has incremented 10 times (due to our base-10 number system). You can just divide your counter by 10, 100, 1000, etc., to get each digit to populate your array.

Comment: @siliconwafer that would be way too slow... anyway to return an int64 value?

Comment: @vvvsg Q1, make the function the same type as `div_result` which is `long long`. Q2, you want `div_result` to be an array. That's the coding style of the operands innit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your own little bigint plus increment functionality:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXDIGITS=12;

void inc(int bignum[MAXDIGITS])
{
    ++bignum[MAXDIGITS-1];
    int carry=0;
    for(int i = MAXDIGITS-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        bignum[i] += carry;
        if(bignum[i]>9)
        {
            carry = 1;
            bignum[i] = 0;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int div_result[MAXDIGITS] = {0};

    // test inc function
    for(int i=0; i<9999991; ++i)
        inc(div_result);

    for(int i=0; i<MAXDIGITS; ++i)
        cout << div_result[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the important part `inc` would be same in C I guess.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that OP didn't write the bigint functions he is calling, otherwise he would not be having this trouble, and would have used the same scheme for his counter..

Comment: I DID RIGHT MY BIG INT FUNC. anyway i'm gonna use unsigned long long.

Comment: @WeatherVane: ha, right, would save another instruction

Answer (score 0):

Well since I worked on your original question, I'll go ahead and post the results for that as well in case you change your mind. Converting a number to an array can be approached in a number of ways. Here is one scheme using a recursive function and a helper to correct the order of the digits.

**note:** for 32-bit OS, overflow will occurr due to x86 utilizing a **4-bit** `long`, a 32-bit safe version using **8-bit** `long long` is included below, a 3rd version using preprocessor directives integrating both versions is included at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXDIG 32

void digits2array (long x, long *a, size_t *idx);
int digits2array_rev (long x, long *a, size_t *i);

int main (void) {

    long n = 25464878454;
    long ar[MAXDIG] = {0};
    size_t idx = 0;
    int i = 0;

    digits2array (n, ar, &idx);    /* convert n to array    */

    printf ("\n array:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* output results       */
        printf ("   ar[%2d] : %ld\n", i, ar[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* converts x to array of digits in a (reverse order) */
int digits2array_rev (long x, long *a, size_t *i) 
{
    if (x < 10) {
        a[(*i)++] = x;
        return x;
    }

    a[(*i)++] = x % 10;

    return digits2array_rev (x / 10, a, i);
}

/* helper function to reverse results of digits2array_rev */
void digits2array (long x, long *a, size_t *idx)
{
    long tmp[MAXDIG] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    digits2array_rev (x, tmp, idx);     /* fill array with digits (reversed) */

    for (i = 0; i < *idx; i++)          /* reverse to correct order */
        a[*idx - 1 - i] = tmp[i];
}
```

**Output/Results**

```
$ ./bin/digits2array

 array:

   ar[ 0] : 2
   ar[ 1] : 5
   ar[ 2] : 4
   ar[ 3] : 6
   ar[ 4] : 4
   ar[ 5] : 8
   ar[ 6] : 7
   ar[ 7] : 8
   ar[ 8] : 4
   ar[ 9] : 5
   ar[10] : 4
```

---

### 32-bit Safe Version (using long long)

On 32-bit OS's overflow would still occur. Changing the types to long long (8-bit `int` on x86), allows the program to operate on x86 without issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXDIG 32

void digits2array (long long x, long long *a, size_t *idx);
long long digits2array_rev (long long x, long long *a, size_t *i);

int main (void) {

    long long n = 25464878454;
    long long ar[MAXDIG] = {0};
    size_t idx = 0;
    int i = 0;

    digits2array (n, ar, &idx);    /* convert n to array    */

    printf ("\n array:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* output results       */
        printf ("   ar[%2d] : %lld\n", i, ar[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* converts x to array of digits in a (reverse order) */
long long digits2array_rev (long long x, long long *a, size_t *i) 
{
    if (x < 10) {
        a[(*i)++] = x;
        return x;
    }

    a[(*i)++] = x % 10;

    return digits2array_rev (x / 10, a, i);
}

/* helper function to reverse results of digits2array_rev */
void digits2array (long long x, long long *a, size_t *idx)
{
    long long tmp[MAXDIG] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    digits2array_rev (x, tmp, idx);     /* fill array with digits (reversed) */

    for (i = 0; i < *idx; i++)          /* reverse to correct order */
        a[*idx - 1 - i] = tmp[i];
}
```

---

### 64/32-bit Version w/Preprocessor Directives

You can accomplish the same thing for x86, while preserving the original types for x86_64 through the use of preprocessor directives. (understanding that there is actually no storage benefit -- `long` (8-bit on x86_64), `long long` (8-bit on x86)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

#define MAXDIG 32

#ifdef BUILD_64
void digits2array (long x, long *a, size_t *idx);
int digits2array_rev (long x, long *a, size_t *i);
#else
void digits2array (long long x, long long *a, size_t *idx);
long long digits2array_rev (long long x, long long *a, size_t *i);
#endif

int main (void) {

#ifdef BUILD_64
    long n = 25464878454;
    long ar[MAXDIG] = {0};
#else
    long long n = 25464878454;
    long long ar[MAXDIG] = {0};
#endif
    size_t idx = 0;
    int i = 0;

    digits2array (n, ar, &idx);    /* convert n to array    */

    printf ("\n array:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)       /* output results       */
#ifdef BUILD_64
        printf ("   ar[%2d] : %ld\n", i, ar[i]);
#else
        printf ("   ar[%2d] : %lld\n", i, ar[i]);
#endif

    return 0;
}

/* converts x to array of digits in a (reverse order) */
#ifdef BUILD_64
int digits2array_rev (long x, long *a, size_t *i)
#else
long long digits2array_rev (long long x, long long *a, size_t *i)
#endif
{
    if (x < 10) {
        a[(*i)++] = x;
        return x;
    }

    a[(*i)++] = x % 10;

    return digits2array_rev (x / 10, a, i);
}

/* helper function to reverse results of digits2array_rev */
#ifdef BUILD_64
void digits2array (long x, long *a, size_t *idx)
{
    long tmp[MAXDIG] = {0};
#else
void digits2array (long long x, long long *a, size_t *idx)
{
    long long tmp[MAXDIG] = {0};
#endif
    int i = 0;

    digits2array_rev (x, tmp, idx);     /* fill array with digits (reversed) */

    for (i = 0; i < *idx; i++)          /* reverse to correct order */
        a[*idx - 1 - i] = tmp[i];
}
```

Comment: my compilers output is : ar[ 0] : -304925322

Comment: Are you using the **exact** data types? I just I just copied/pasted and got the exact same results. What are you running this on? Hold on, you must be running on a 32-bit box. Give me a bit and I'll update it.

Comment: I was thinking, one way to improve the efficiency of your code, would be to use a normal increment until you hit the  upper limit of `25464878454`, then convert it to an array using this code, then proceed with the BigNum scheme that increments the array. That would save you `25464878454` function calls/branches to the BigNum scheme when it is not necessary.